# Change file names with powershell DMY -> YMD

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, date, powershell-2.0

I have to change alot of files on a Windows computer and I will be using Powershell to do it.

The file names are like name_name_DDMMYYYY_XXXXXX.bmp

- John_Doe_03062009_123456.bmp
- John_Doe_27122016_567890.bmp

I would like to have it sort it like name_name_YYYYMMDD_XXXXXX.bmp

- John_Doe_20090603_123456.bmp
- John_Doe_20161227_567890.bmp

I'm a total amature in Powershell and just got started with replacing special characters to nothing. So all help is great!

Comment: `-replace '_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})_', '_${3}${2}${1}_'`

Comment: That's clever @AnsgarWiechers You should post it as an answer.

Comment: It's actually pretty basic.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - You should still post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 8 digits you want to match and reorder are between underscores, so you could do something like this:

```
$pattern = '_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})_'
'John_Doe_03062009_123456.bmp' -replace $pattern, '_${3}${2}${1}_'
```

The pattern matches 8 digits between underscores in 3 capturing groups, so that you can reorder the captured substrings via backreferences (`$1`, `$2`, `$3`).

For further help on the `-replace` operator see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-3.0#replacement-operator). For further help on regular expression syntax see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference). There are some slight differences between PowerShell and plain .Net, like backreference syntax (`\1` vs `$1`), but most of it can be applied directly.

Comment: Thanks for you help! Read about it, but still have a hard time to change the name on the files. Don't really get how to pipe all the file names to the replacement script. 

I done this 

$pattern = '_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})_'
(ls).name -replace $pattern, '_${3}${2}${1}_'

Its just list the changed names of them in Powershell, then acually changing name on the files :P

Comment: I went with the answer that gave me this soloution
ls | %{ ren $_ $(($_.name -replace '_(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})_', '_${3}${2}${1}_'))}

Comment: `ls | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace ...}`